# How to prove ¬(P ∧ ¬Q), ¬P → Q ∴ Q using Fitch-style natural deduction system?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Once again, for the argument ¬(P ∧ ¬Q), ¬P → Q ∴ Q, I am trying to prove it using fitch style natural deduction system. However, I run into a problem with ∧Elim for ¬(P ∧ ¬Q). I can't get anything out of ¬(P ∧ ¬Q). I am a little confused about how to proceed with this one. Although it still seems fairly easy. Anyone can demonstrate this? Thank you!

Allowed inference rules: ∨I, ∨E, ∧I, ∧E, →I, →E, ¬I, ¬E, X, DS, IP. [image: ¬(P ∧ ¬Q), ¬P → Q ∴ Q]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ∧Intro with lines 3 and 7 which gives (P ∧ ¬Q) . This contradicts ¬ (P ∧ ¬Q) on line 1, so your initial assumption of ¬Q must be false, hence Q is true

Comment: thank you so much!